# Doctrine2 Native SQL Alias without Annotations

Tags: symfony, geolocation, doctrine-orm, alias

I have a problem with the native SQL in Doctrine 2.

The main problem is that the alias does not work. I can only map a SQL-Alias to the entity by adding an annotation. This works fine, if I do it. But it's not really good in production because I have to delete the field in the db first.

I want to build a query with a location based distance in meters but it's not really practical to do it in doctrine so far. I mean it's not something special to get an alias from query.

`SELECT *, (RADIANS( ? )) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS( ? )) + SIN(RADIANS( ? )) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) AS distance`
is nothing special in my opinion

Why do I have to handle this alone?